# Apache clone domain / server

Tags: apache, multiserver

is it possible to 'clone' a domain in 2 different servers?

what is want is:

send all requests of domain1.com also to domain2.com 
so actually domain1 and domain2 are both live and in sync, but are running on other servers.

With this, i want to make a 'live backup' domein/server

i am using directadmin (apache/mysql)

i have tried different options live syncing whit Rsync or r1soft to backup the domein, but because of the size (50/100gb) of the data, backups are taking too long. so the backup is always 1 hour or more behind.

Comment: What is your goal: more robustness against domain name resolution issues (http requests failing) or system failures (disks crashing)? Reason why I ask: the term "server" is often used incorrectly for a system which actually it just refers to the http service.

Comment: what is want is a situation that my application (php/sql) has alwas a live backup (with max 1/5 minutes delay) so if somehow the first domain/server/hardware crashes  i always have a very resent backup or even better a live serve that is still working

Comment: Ok, so you need to implement mysql replication (google for that) and some permanent file system synchronization (maybe csync based). That means a lot of network traffic which will slow down your systems.

Comment: A _much_ cheaper alternative would be _not_ to synchronize but to keep both storage locations (mysql and file system) in a shared location, maybe a third system. You can access them internally via network. That _does_ work, allows one server system to crash, but has the disadvantage that you still have your data storage as a single point of failure.

Comment: True, but the whole point is to get the data safe at minimum 2 locations

Comment: Another question: why do you need two domains for that? Why not have two systems serve the same domain and use a load balancer upfront? Doesn't that make more sense with the look on robustness and redundancy?

Comment: You need replication for the mysql server, no way around that. For the file system storage: an alternative to explicit syncing might be a federated file system approach, something like xtreemfs.